# If I want to deodorize my carpet with baking soda, should I spray water on the baking soda?

Tags: carpet

https://web.archive.org/web/20160715111807/http://www.housekeepinghere.com/weekly/baking-soda-carpets/ says that I should keep the carpet dry, while http://www.repair-home.com/flooring/carpet/carpet-cleaning-solutions.html says that I should spray the area with water.

Answer (score 8):

Baking soda needs to be in contact with the odors to work.  If the baking soda is wet, it will not really work at all because the water will be blocking the odors from getting near the surface of the baking soda.  I also suspect it would be a real mess to clean up.

In the past I've tried baking soda on carpets (dry!) and found it to be a waste of time.  A professional steam cleaning is probably the most effective solution.

Comment: Oh wow, I see. =/ Well, could I wait for the water to evaporate then?

Comment: Instead of a fine powder which is easy to vacuum you'll end up with clumpy baking soda that might even be stuck to the surface you sprayed it on.  Keep it dry.

Answer (score 1):

I use baking soda all over my rugs, carpets, and the dog's bed a couple times a year. I think it works great. This is just normal house/dog smell I'm trying to get rid of, not smoke or animal excrement thankfully. I wouldn't wet it bc like a previous commenter mentioned it would become clumpy and not as easy to vacuum up.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.